# How to change UIButton without reset position?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift4, uipangesturerecognizer

I have made a draggable button

```
let buttonGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggedButton(_:)))
menuButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
menuButton.addGestureRecognizer(buttonGesture)
```

When the button drag to certain position, image will be changed.

```
@objc func draggedButton(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: menuButton)
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)

    menuButton.center = CGPoint(x: menuButton.center.x + translation.x, y: menuButton.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    if(menuButton.center.x < 100){
        menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "newimage"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}
```

But after setImage, button will reset position, how to prevent this?

Comment: I tried this and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Try setting button background image instead of button image. Since setting image will rescale its position.

Comment: I have also tried it and when I drag to origin less than 100 its updating the image and the button's frame is not resetting to its original position. Can you add any sample images so that I can get a clear picture of the issue.

Comment: Is video ok? I have recorded a video. `https://streamable.com/43jar`, image and background image are same.

Comment: I also try this, `https://streamable.com/uk1dz`, even I set image to other button, it still reset position. First video I use `setImage`, second video I use `setBackgroundImage`, you can see they are no different

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and heres my solution:

1. unset the image, make button blank with no graphics in it
2. create new **UIImageView** including your **UIImages**, for initial and second state
3. in ***viewDidLoad*()** in **UIViewController** set **UIImageView**.***bounds*** = **UIButton**.***bounds*** set the initial image
4. call **UIButton.*addSubview*(UIImageView)**
5. in your method where you are using UIButton.setImage() call **UIImageView**.***image*** = **UIImage**

Heres an example:

```
    class VC : UIViewController{
       let image_initial : UIImage = UIImage("img_1")
       let image_second : UIImage = UIImage("img_2")
       let imageview_menu : UIImageView = UIImageView()
       @IBOutlet weak var button_menu: UIButton!

       override func viewDidLoad(){
           super.viewDidLoad()
           //...
           self.imageview_menu.bounds = button_menu.bounds
           self.imageview_menu.image = image_initial
           self.button_menu.addSubview(imageview_menu)
           //...
       }
       @objc func draggedButton(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
           //...your code
           if(menuButton.center.x < 100){
              imageview_menu.image = image_second
           }

       }
    }
```

Hope this helps if you haven't found solution. :)